# How should I handle "no-gap" and not "extra-width" in Twitter Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all take a look to this picture:

[image: example]

I'm trying to build this using Twitter Bootstrap (3.2.0) but doesn't know how to. So after read TB docs and Google some resources I came with this possible solutions:

- Not use `row` and `cols-x` class from TB which may cause issues later for responsiveness and so on
- Use them and overwrite the behavior by removing any `padding` or `margin` causing the gap between the two `div`

In this case which one should I use? What yours use on this cases?

As second question and related to the same:

- How do yours calculate the right `cols-x` to apply in order to get as close as image width is? Any formula? Right now I'm doing using Firebug and applying cols on the fly but this is insane, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make two columns without gaps between each use own custom columns